# Extend Date prototype with a interface Typescript

Tags: javascript, date, interface, typescript

I want to add a getWeekNumber function to the Date prototype in javascript / typescript. I want to do it with an interface becease otherwise I get a error that he does not know the method getWeekNumber().

First I tried with a standart Date interface like this:

```
interface Date {
    getWeekNumber(): number;
}
```

This had the resolve that all the methods of the Date are not call able anymore.

I want to know of there is a way to extend the Date with an interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it this way:

in DateExt.ts:

```
interface Date 
{
    getWeekNumber: () => number;
}

Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function() 
{
    return 123;//your calculations goes here
};
```

in your app.ts:

```
import './DateExt';

let a = new Date();
console.log(a.getWeekNumber());
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that all the Date methods are not avaible anymore like `getTime()` or `getDate()`

Comment: They are available. Its an issue with your IDE. I have latest VSCode / Typescript and it works like a charm.

Comment: also my ionic CLI crasht and the application itself

Comment: Sorry my fault. I exported the interface and imported it with {Date}